# Search & Replace in Text files - With a RegEx Variable Pattern

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to replace a string in each file lets call the string XXX
I would like to replace it with the regex pattern variable text found between Start and END

Currently it simply replaces the word, and then just does not replace.

```
$Pat1 = [regex]  '(START)*(END)'      # Find Variable between these 2 first

Get-ChildItem * -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"
} | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -replace "XXX","$Pat1" | Set-Content -path $_
}
```

## Example Text Below

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque porttitor augue quis urna suscipit lobortis. Cras eu magna sem. Quisque dictum feugiat convallis.

START  **File Name 1** END
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque porttitor augue quis urna suscipit lobortis. Cras eu magna sem. Quisque dictum feugiat convallis.

**XXX**  Vestibulum risus quam, volutpat iaculis ipsum in, vehicula dictum urna. Suspendisse dui tortor, faucibus et tellus vitae, malesuada consequat velit.

=================================

Comment: You never executed a match for `$Pat1`, so you're replacing with a null value.

Comment: Hi TMT -  do I add it like this  "$Pat1" -match

Comment: I have been trying this  also:  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "XXX", "(?i)(?<=START ).*?(?= *END)"} |  - nothing seems to work  :(

Comment: Con you give exemple of what you've got in your files and what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very unclear, but I'm guessing that you want to replace `XXX` with the value between `START` and `END` in the file and the not regex-pattern itself. If so, try this:

```
$Pat1 = [regex]  'START(.*?)END'      #Find Variable between these 2 first

Get-ChildItem * -Recurse  | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
ForEach-Object {
    $text = (Get-Content $_ -Raw)
    $value = [regex]::Match($text, $Pat1).Groups[1].Value
    $text -replace "XXX",$value | Set-Content -path $_
}
```

Be aware the `-replace` works like `'text' -replace 'regex-pattern', 'stringvalue'` The right value does not accept a regex-pattern, but only a string (which may include `$0`,`$1` etc. to add the full match, captured group 1 etc.)

Comment: Hi Frode, sadly it did not replace :(  - hence I posted the sample  The XXX is removed from file only

Comment: It works for me. It replaced XXX with `File Name 1`. Nothing changed? What PowerShell version are you using? Does it work if you change to `$text = (Get-Content $_ -Raw)`?

Comment: Frode - Smashing Man  - thank you!    I am using the Powershell 5.0   - it worked!!

Comment: Frode - just a quick question , if I have multiple XXX in the same file will all of them get replaced ?

Comment: Thank you :) - It worked  - I am grateful for your help .  I spent ages yesterday trying to figure  this out.